# Can't seeing python script output in nohup.out file

Tags: python-3.x, bash, nohup

I have a bash script that executes in loop a python script:

```
 while true; do python3 script.py && break; done
```

launched with `nohup`:

```
nohup ./run_script.sh &
```

Why if I run the command:

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

I don't see the output of the python script?

I correctly see the script in my running process:

```
pi        2757  1.5  3.4  37268 33064 ?        S    15:06   0:18 python3 script.py
pi        2819  0.0  0.0   1908   388 ?        S    15:07   0:00 /bin/sh ./run_script.sh
pi        2820  1.6  3.5  37268 33096 ?        S    15:07   0:18 python3 script.py
```

If I directly launch the python script with `nohup`, I see the output but I need to relaunch the script everytime it fails, so I need to lauch it with the bash script

Maybe I'm missing some concept concerning `nohup` usage.

Comment: What output do you expect from 'tail -f run_script.sh' ?

Comment: The output of the python script

Comment: It should be in nohup.log (tail -f nohup.log).

Comment: There isn't any output...

Comment: What is the output of the python script  ? is the script still running (use ps). Why does the whlie loop break after the first invocation ? Also note that nohup.log is placed in the home folder, and only capture stdout.

Comment: I have some print in the python script... I expect to see it. The nohup.out file is in the current directory and it is empty. Please, read the question updated

Comment: I resolved! It was due to output buffering, if I launch the script with the `python -u` option, the `nohup.out` log file it's no more empy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved modifing the script in this way:

```
while true; do python3 -u script.py && break; done
```

The output file `nohup.out` during execution remains empty until the execution is finished. This happens because of output buffering. Adding the `-u` flag I can avoid output buffering.

For other details see this blog page https://janakiev.com/blog/python-background/.